# In VS Code when editing python files, is there a command/shortcut to unindent a line?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My VS Code shortcuts for changing indent look like this:
[image: Reindent Lines]

This works fine in JavaScript/TypeScript, but in Python files the reindent commands have no effect. (I expect them to shift the text 4 spaces to the left, removing one indent level.) The normal indent command works fine. I use the Python and Pylance extensions. No other extensions related to Python or text editing.

Tried using different keybindings. Reset all VS Code settings. Disabled all extensions.

Edit: It may be that I misunderstood what "reindent " means. What I guess what I am looking for is "unindent". I know it can change what scope a line belongs to in Python, that's why I want it: In case I made a mistake and put code in a loop or if branch when I actually didn't want to.

Comment: I’d understand “reindent” to fix uneven indentation, not to *unindent* lines…!?

Comment: On other language, indent has no syntax meaning but for linting. So what ever indent the lint tool make wont change the codebase syntax meaning. This is not apply for python which 1 different in indent can cause syntax error or make different in code meaning. So on python wont have such tool to help indent but you have to do it by yourself.

Comment: I would also think "unindent" is the right word, but there is no such command, and in other  languages "reindent" is working like that, removing one indention level. But maybe it indeed means something else and my assumption was wrong.

Comment: With the vim-plugin for vscode you can use a quick `<`+`<` or `>`+`>` in normal mode. I leave this here for people who use the vim-bindings but I do not recommend installing the plugin just for that.

Comment: Just use tab to indent and shift + tab to unindent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a keybinding to not apply for a particular language, then adjust your when clause using the `editorLangId` when clause context. Ex.

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "editor.action.reindentlines",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && editorLangId != python"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not a solution to my specific problem.

Comment: @TimBuschtöns I'd encourage you to try to clarify your problem in your question post, because I cannot understand what it is from your question post.